# Why is it blank when I do summation in kdb?

Tags: kdb

I did a simple query:

```
select sum(sol) from data
```

and it returned blank for the result. I checked if there is any null and it doesn't have any null value. How can I know what was wrong?

Comment: What do the following statements return? 
q)meta data 
q)count data 

Thanks

Comment: are you doing this via console, or some UI like Studio?

Comment: What does -3!select sum(sol) from data return?

Answer (score 2):

make sure you are not assigning the result to a variable or ending the line with a semi-colon as these will suppress the immediate output of the results.

```
q)data:([]sol:1 2 3 4 5)
q)
q) /Expected result.
q)select sum(sol) from data
sol
---
15
q)
q) /Output suppressed by semi-colon.
q)select sum(sol) from data;
q)
q) /Output suppressed by variable assignment.
q)example:select sum(sol) from data
q)
```

Also, even if data has no records in it (eg: count data = 0) it will still output the column name but with no results underneath.

```
q)data:([]sol:())
q)
q)select sum(sol) from data
sol
---

q)
```

A null value in the data set shouldn't effect the output (Of sum at least) but if you want to replace the null values (with zero for example you could do this)

```
q)update 0^sol from `data
```

This use's the [^ (fill)](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#fill) operator.

Comment: thanks! when I did the query select col from data, it gives all the values. but when i did select sum(col) from data, it gives the column name and a blank. not really sure why. I did not type semicolon after that. I checked there is no null value

Comment: maybe its one of the values in the column is not the int. Do you know how I can exclude the value out?

Comment: It seems to me that this should be working for you, if you aren't assigning a variable or ending with a semi colon. The i means that it is a column of integers which sum works perfectly fine on. Ensure you are using the correct column name in the statement. (As you have col in your comment but sol in the question)

Comment: what does 'q)sol' return? It is possible you have a global variable set in your session, and thus 'sum(sol)' is not referring to the column within your table 'data'.

Comment: A bit late, but see my additional response @Terry

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that your sum is too big to be stored as integer? That would create a blank/null

```
q)tab:([] col1:1 2i,0Wi-1i)
q)
q)tab
col1
----------
1
2
2147483646
q)
q)meta tab
c   | t f a
----| -----
col1| i
q)
q)
q)select sum col1 from tab
col1
----

q)
```